# How to plot graph between -0.1 and 0.1 in python using matplot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph for this function using python:

(|1+x|-1)/2x

What i got so far is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-0.10,0.10,10)
y = ((np.abs(1+x)-1)/(2*x))

plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylabel('y axis')

# Create the plot
plt.plot(x, y)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

the weird thing is that when i plot the same graph at the interval [-2,2], everything works fine, it's just [-0.1,0.1] that is not working and giving a very weird graph. Is there anything i'm missing? thanks

Comment: Please explain just how "everything work[ed] fine" in the interval `[-2, 2]` but "is not working and giving a very weird graph" in the interval `[-0.1, 0.1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `np.abs(1+x)-1` is equal to `x` whenever `x` is greater than or equal to `-1`. Therefore your entire expression `((np.abs(1+x)-1)/(2*x))` equals `x/(2*x)` which is just `1/2` or `0.5` for `x >= -1` and `x != 0`.

So whenever your bounds are greater than or equal to `-1` you will just get a section of the line `y= 0.5`. You did not see this when your bounds were `-2` to `2` since that includes some domain where `y` is not constant.

Did you mean to use a different formula for your graph?

When you used the bounds `-2` to `2` you should have seen the horizontal line on the middle and right side of the graph. Here is your graph with the ten points in your code (see the `linspace` line).

[image]

Here is the graph with more points (`101`) with the number of points chosen to ensure that `0` is part of the plotted domain. Here you can more clearly see that the left side is not constant but the rest is, with the exception of the hole (removable discontinuity) at `x = 0`.

[image]

Comment: You can add a small value such 1e-6 for better numerical stability. I mean by having: `np.abs(1.0 + x + 1e-6)` In this case having 0.5 everywhere for range [-0.1, 0.1] is avoided but still not sure if this is a good solution.